# @SequenceGenerator is not working

Tags: java, hibernate

Today I got very strange behavior. I have declared a model with a primary key that uses `@SequenceGenerator`:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="EMP_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="EMP_SEQ")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="EMP_SEQ_GEN_GEN")
@Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Long getEmpId() {
   return this.empId;
}
```

It works locally but it doesn't work on the server. I have connected to the same database from both environments.

Answer (score 1):

I think your @GeneratedValue should look like @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMP_SEQ_GEN").